# Python Generate truthtable from expression containing Numeric value and comparators

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, truthtable

I am trying to generate test cases from a boolean expression which may contain numerical values and comparators, e.g.:

> (10 < a) and (c == 5)

truth tables seems like a good approach and generation output might look like this:

```
>  a,  c, result
> 11,  5,   True,
> 11,  4,  False,
>  9,  5,  False,
>  9,  4,  False
```

It is pretty straight forward to generate a truth table when expression only contains boolean operators using ast.nodevisitor. I ended up with something like this which works nicely.

```
class Expr():

    def __init__(self, expr):
        self.tree = ast.parse(expr)
        self.expr=expr
        self.vars = self.allVariables().visit(self.tree)
        self.generateTruthTable()

    def generateTruthTable(self):
        NO_GLOBALS = {'__builtins__': {}}
        self.truthtable=dict()
        for i, vals in enumerate(product([True,False],repeat=len(self.vars))):
            self.truthtable[i] = dict()
            self.truthtable[i]['inputs'] = dict(zip(self.vars, vals))
            self.truthtable[i]['expectation'] = eval(self.expr, NO_GLOBALS, self.truthtable[i]['inputs'])

    class allVariables(ast.NodeVisitor):
        def visit_Module(self, node):
            self.names = set()
            self.generic_visit(node)
            return sorted(self.names)

        def visit_Name(self, node):
            self.names.add(node.id)
```

now I am deeply struggling in how to perform this same generation whatever the operators are. it looks like recursion is key here. is there a way to perform such generation using python AST ?
thank you.

Comment: Do you know the variables in the expression, or do you have to find those out first? Also, can the expression be "trusted", i.e. could you just `eval` it?

Comment: the expression can be trusted and the expected result can evaluated using eval. I do not know the variables from the start that why I have created this allVariables visitor to retrieve them

Comment: If you do not know the variables, where do the values come from? (Asking because in your example they are not the same for each variable, so some knowledge about the variables seemed likely.)

Comment: In my output example, I set the variable to values that would cause left part of the and operation true or false if a = 11 then 10 < a is True if a = 9 then 10 < a is False. But it could have been 100 and 0. hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem, I just had to constrain the usage to prevent that numerical value end to the right of an operation and also limited the possibility in term of operators.

```
import ast
import operator
from itertools import product

class OperatorError(Exception):
    pass

class Expr():

    BOOLOP_SYMBOLS = (
        ast.And,
        ast.Or
    )

    UNARYOP_SYMBOLS = (
        ast.Not
    )

    BINOP_SYMBOLS = (
        ast.BitAnd,
        ast.BitXor,
        ast.Pow
    )

    CMPOP_SYMBOLS = (
        ast.Eq,
        ast.Gt,
        ast.GtE,
        ast.Lt,
        ast.LtE,
        ast.NotEq
    )

    def __init__(self, expr):
        self.tree = ast.parse(expr)
        self.expr=expr
        self.vars = self.SyntaxChecker().visit(self.tree)
        self.tt = self.generateTruthTable()

    def generateTruthTable(self):
        NO_GLOBALS = {'__builtins__': {}}
        truthtable=dict()
        for i, vals in enumerate(product([True,False],repeat=len(self.vars.keys()))):
            truthtable[i] = dict()
            vals_convert=[]
            for j,k in enumerate(self.vars.iterkeys()):
                vals_convert.append(self.vars[k][vals[j]])
            truthtable[i]['inputs'] = dict(zip(self.vars.keys(), vals_convert))
            truthtable[i]['expectation'] = eval(self.expr, NO_GLOBALS, truthtable[i]['inputs'])
        return truthtable

    class SyntaxChecker(ast.NodeVisitor):

        def visit_Module(self, module):
            self.vars = dict()
            self.generic_visit(module)
            return self.vars

        def visit_Expr(self, expr):
            return self.visit(expr.value)

        def visit_BoolOp(self, boolop):
            if isinstance(boolop.op, Expr.BOOLOP_SYMBOLS):
                left,right = map(self.visit, boolop.values)
                return [left, right]
            else:
                raise OperatorError(Expr.BOOLOP_SYMBOLS[boolop.op] + ' is not supported.')

        def visit_BinOp(self, binop):
            if isinstance(binop.op, Expr.BINOP_SYMBOLS):
                left , right = map(self.visit, [binop.left, binop.right])
                if isinstance(binop.op, ast.BitAnd):
                    self.vars[left] = {True: right, False: 0}
                if isinstance(binop.op, ast.BitXor):
                    self.vars[left] = {True: 0, False: right}
                if isinstance(binop.op, ast.Pow):
                    return left ** right
            else:
                raise OperatorError(Expr.BINOP_SYMBOLS[binop.op] + ' is not supported.')

        def visit_Compare(self, cmpop):
            if isinstance(cmpop.ops[0], Expr.CMPOP_SYMBOLS):
                left = self.visit(cmpop.left)
                right = self.visit(cmpop.comparators[0])
                if isinstance(cmpop.ops[0], ast.Gt):
                    self.vars[left] = {True: right + 1, False: right - 1}
                elif isinstance(cmpop.ops[0], ast.GtE):
                    self.vars[left] = {True: right, False: right - 1}
                elif isinstance(cmpop.ops[0], ast.Lt):
                    self.vars[left] = {True: right-1, False: right + 1}
                elif isinstance(cmpop.ops[0], ast.LtE):
                    self.vars[left] = {True: right, False: right + 1}
                elif isinstance(cmpop.ops[0], ast.Eq):
                    self.vars[left] = {True: right, False: right + 1}
                elif isinstance(cmpop.ops[0], ast.NotEq):
                    self.vars[left] = {True: right + 1, False: right}
            else:
                raise OperatorError(Expr.CMPOP_SYMBOLS[cmpop.ops] + ' is not supported.')

        def visit_UnaryOp(self, unaryop):
            if isinstance(unaryop.op, Expr.UNARYOP_SYMBOLS):
                right= self.visit(unaryop.operand)
                self.vars[right] = {True: False, False: True}
            else:
                raise OperatorError(Expr.UNARYOP_SYMBOLS[unaryop.op] + ' is not supported.')

        def visit_Num(self, num):
            return num.n

        def visit_Name(self, node):
            self.vars[node.id] = {True: True, False: False}
            return node.id
```

with the example:

> (a < 10) and (c == 5)

I can generate the following output:

> {
>   0: {'inputs': {'a': 9, 'c': 5}, 'expectation': True}, 
>   1: {'inputs': {'a': 9, 'c': 6}, 'expectation': False},
>   2: {'inputs': {'a': 11, 'c': 5}, 'expectation': False},
>   3: {'inputs': {'a': 11, 'c': 6}, 'expectation': False}  }

feel free to suggest any improvement to this solution.